How to use openxml to properly process the header so that it can be displayed properly?
I have a template document that uses openxml processing, and the original document body and header are displayed normally, after I made some changes in the document body (for example, removing one of the options of a dropdown control), the content of the document header that is dynamically filled with variables via tag is not displayed properly.
I tried to put the header processing in front of the body processing in the code, and the header appeared normal again.But I know this processing order is not very reasonable, can anyone give me a better suggestion to deal with this problem?
